# How to open about:addons from a Firefox WebExtensions addon?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

When I attempt to open about: addons with the tabs API as follows:

```
  function onCreated(tab) {
    console.log(`Created new tab: ${tab.id}`)
  }

  function onError(error) {
    console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
  }

  var creating = chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'about:addons'
  });

  creating.then(onCreated, onError);
```

I get the following error:

```
21:56:49.702 Unchecked lastError value: Error: Illegal URL: about:addons 1 ExtensionCommon.jsm:304
    withLastError resource://gre/modules/ExtensionCommon.jsm:304:9
    wrapPromise/< resource://gre/modules/ExtensionCommon.jsm:357:11
```

I see in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create) that such 'privileged' URLs are not allowed, but according to the roadmap (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1269456), this will be implemented in the future

Meantime, does anyone know of a workaround ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are asking this here. You already found the bug covering making the changes needed to allow you to do what you want. You already requested a status update on it (presumably it's you who has asked on the bug, as such request was posted at about the same time as this question). You can clearly see that the status of the bug is that it's open, not resolved-fixed, it's not even assigned to someone to actually work on implementing it. Why do you think there will be a good answer available to you here?

Comment: I am asking for a workaround, is that so strange?

Comment: There is no workaround possible for what you want. The closest thing is browser.runtime.openOptionsPage.